# Informatica target table populating

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I am new in Informatica,here i am trying to populate my target table by joining two tables where the no. of rows in both the table is 5649 and 2611 respectively.So, my output rows should be 8260.But the no. of rows rows in target table is around 108860 (approx.).

Why this is happening and how should I remove it?

Comment: Are you sure you want to "join" the tables ?  From the sound of it, looks like that you are trying to achieve is a "stich" or union, wherein the data from one attaches itself to the other table... please clarify with some examples here..

Comment: The join is not based on unique Keys. So, whats happening is non key join and it is resulting multiple rows. For example, if one table has values like a1, a1 and second table has values like a1,a1,a1. You expect 2/3 records as output, but you will get 6(3x2).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are confusing the [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) operation with [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#UNION_operator).

You need to merge two sets of rows into one, so use a `Union` transformation, not a `Joiner`.

Comment: Thankyou,for your reply.But the table structure of both the table is not same.

Comment: @coolmego Can you edit your questions and post an example to describe your requirements? Without that it's impossible to tell what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

if table structure isn't same pick/select only common columns and then perform a union in SQ Override..